# Allowing only the numbers in PasswordBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, passwordbox

I want to be enter **numbers only** and does not allow non-numbers, please help me with this.

this Code in TextBox But it does not work with PasswordBox

```
        Dim textBox As TextBox = TryCast(sender, TextBox)
        Dim selectionStart As Int32 = textBox.SelectionStart
        Dim selectionLength As Int32 = textBox.SelectionLength
        Dim newText As [String] = [String].Empty
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For Each c As [Char] In textBox.Text.ToCharArray()
            If [Char].IsDigit(c) OrElse [Char].IsControl(c) Then
                newText += c
            End If
        Next
        textBox.Text = newText
        textBox.SelectionStart = If(selectionStart <= textBox.Text.Length, selectionStart, textBox.Text.Length)
```

thank you

Comment: Why don't you put what you have tried so far? Off the top of my head, I would have the password box subscribe to the keyup and keydown events and you can check there if the last char was a numeric option.

Comment: I put the code that was working with me in TextBox

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub PbPhone_PreviewTextInput(sender As Object, e As TextCompositionEventArgs) Handles PbPhone.PreviewTextInput
    Dim regex As New Regex("[0-9]+")
    If Not regex.IsMatch(e.Text) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Previously code will only accept the numbers, though the introduction of a character, you will not be writing

Comment: Always try to explain what some code does. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer